# how to apply app.use to many links which takes us to the same link?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have static 3 HTML pages and the pages are running on localhost:3000. I inserted the links in HTML, so that clicking on them I can switch from this page to another one. And I wrote the code in my js file like this:

```js
app.use("/bbb.html", function (req, res, html) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/bbb.html");
});



app.use("/", function (req, res, html) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});


app.use("/ccc.html", function (req, res, html) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/ccc.html");
});
```

In all of the HTML pages I added corresponding links in this format:

```html
<a href="/bbb"></a>    
<a href="/index"></a>       
<a href="/ccc"></a>
```

The first 2 codes work, but the 3rd one which has to take to ccc.html doesn't work.
I assume it does not work because on that page where I have placed the link, there are 4 same  anchor tags. So probably I have to specify this in the third code.
How is it possible? (I am a beginner)
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try the static file serving?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work either
Edit: Actually I changed the href link in HTML and wrote the full path, it works. But I need to serve it from localhost

Comment: You are linking to `/ccc`, but the route is `/ccc.html`.  Those are not the same and thus the route does not match.  FYI, you shouldn't be using `app.use()` for just GET requests like this.  You should be using `app.get()`.

Comment: And change your `app.use("/", ...)` to `app.get("/", ...)` because `app.use("/", ...)` is greedy and will match everything.  Don't use `app.use()` unless you want to match all possible http verbs or you want the greedy path matching.  Otherwise pick the precise http verb you want to match.

Comment: /ccc is not a problem in this case, because other two pages also has the same type of link and they work. Also, I have tried GET , it doesn't even show any single page

Comment: Well, you're doing a whole bunch of things wrong here that make route handling unpredictable.  I'm trying to teach you the proper way to declare these routes to make it reliable and predictable. If you don't care to learn the proper way to do things to make this easier, I can stop trying to help.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you for that. I just said app.get did not work, I cannot do anything about it

Comment: `app.get()` works just fine when you get the rest of the parts correct.  Note, it should be `app.get("/ccc.html", ...)` and the URL should be `<a href="/ccc.html">CCC</a>`.  That will work.  Or, `app.get("/ccc", ...)` and `<a href="/ccc">CCC</a>`.  And, convert all `app.use()` you have to `app.get()` so none of them conflict.

Comment: Also, when you declare your routes, it should be `(req, res, next)`, not `(req, res, html)`.  That isn't currently causing a problem because you aren't attempting to use the `html` parameter, but I don't know where you got the idea to name it `html` as it has nothing to do with your html.

Comment: I wrote an answer that summarizes the changes I think you should make.

Answer (score 0):

you are using app.use('/') before app.use('/ccc.html') so when you write localhost:3000/ccc.html on URL it first checks to /bbb.html no it is not matching then it checks to / yes it will be a match because it checks if the prefix is match or not..so you will be serve up app.use('/') not app.use('/ccc.html')

solution..
write app.use('/ccc.html') before app.use('/')

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use("/bbb.html", function (req, res, html) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/bbb.html");
  });
  
  app.use("/ccc.html", function (req, res, html) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/ccc.html");
   });
  
  app.use("/", function (req, res, html) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
  });
  
  

  app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('server is up on port: ',3000)
});
```

and one important thing use is for different purpose.. there is a saying
"***Incomplete knowledge is dangerous***". Go and complete the full tutorial from wherever you are learning node js

Comment: The OP also shouldn't be using `app.use()` for a simple GET as that's part of the problem.   `app.get("/", ...)` wouldn't conflict with the other routes like `app.use()` does.

Comment: I have tried in all orders, and if I change I lose the other page too

Answer (score 0):

Let's attempt to clean this up and solve a bunch of problems:

```
app.get("/bbb", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/bbb.html");
});


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});


app.get("/ccc", function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/ccc.html");
});
```

And, then the links in your pages that come from this same server:

```
<a href="/bbb">bbb</a>    
<a href="/">index</a>       
<a href="/ccc">ccc</a>
```

Things I changed:

1. Use `app.get()` instead of `app.use()` for simple GET requests.
2. Make the links in the `<a>` tags href match the route definitions exactly.
3. Fix the arguments to `app.get()` - there should not be an argument named `html`.  If you planned on using the third route argument, it should be called `next`, but if you're not planning on using it, the convention is to not declare it.

The reasons to not use `app.use()` for simple GET requests are as follows:

1. `app.use()` accepts partial path matches.  You don't want that because `/` will conflict with `/ccc` unless you have strict ordering and you don't want partial matches for these simple routes.
2. You only want to respond to GET requests, not POST, PUT, DELETE, etc... with these routes.

---

FYI, with the proper directory structure on the server, all these files could be served with one line of code using the `express.static()` middleware.  There is generally no need to individually code multiple static routes like this.